# C++ Enum to String Switch Not Working

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, enums, switch-statement

I am instantiating an object with a few enum types and trying to set some string members based on those enum types. However, when I am debugging and step though, the switch used to set the strings hits every case, and each string gets set to the last case for each enum type.

```
enum Number {
one,
two,
three
};

enum Color {
    purple,
    red,
    green
};

enum Shading {
    solid,
    striped,
    outlined
};

enum Shape {
    oval,
    squiggle,
    diamond
};

Card::Card(Number num, Color colour, Shading shade, Shape shaper) {
number_ = num;
color_ = colour;
shading_ = shade;
shape_ = shaper;
setStrings();
}

void Card::setStrings() {
switch (number_) {
case one:
    number_string = "one";
case two:
    number_string = "two";
case three:
    number_string = "three";
}
switch(color_) {
case purple:
    color_string = "purple";
case red:
    color_string = "red";
case green:
    color_string = "green";
}
switch (shading_) {
case solid:
    shading_string = "solid";
case striped:
    shading_string = "striped";
case outlined:
    shading_string = "outlined";
}
switch (shape_) {
case oval:
    shape_string = "oval";
case squiggle:
    shape_string = "squiggle";
case diamond:
    shape_string = "diamond";
}

}
```

Every card I instantiate using the overloaded constructor has number_string = "three", color_string = "green", shading_string = "outlined", and shape_string = "diamond".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your switch-case is not correct. You need to put a `break` after every case for your solution otherwise it will go into every case until it is finished and not break when it hits the case you want.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use break for switch statements' case clause else it is a fall through. Here is an example and details for you. https://10hash.com/c/cf/#idm45440468325552

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  int i  = 65;

  switch(i)
  {
    case 'A':
      printf("Value of i is 'A'.\n");
      break;
    case 'B':
      printf("Value of i is 'B'.\n");
      break;
    default:
      break;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: it will never be a fallthrough but I need breaks

Comment: It will always be a fallthrough if you do not used breaks.